# Converting a char(or string) to key value of it

Tags: c#, key, keycode

I'm not sure if "key value" is correct word for it as there are few formats I believe, what im talking about is http://pastebin.com/XJVx1dB5 this is format where 88 is Z etc. I hope im clear.

I have tried many things, but convert from string function of keys converter class is the only one that is remotely close. The problem is, it converts "x" to 88 as I wanted, however it fails to convert " " or "[" because it expects "SPACE"(string) and not a single space as char I believe.

I used it like this, maybe there is another(correct?) version of using it:

```
((int)kc.ConvertFromString(s))
```

So what I want to do is to get that chars of mine to code ones. How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
 var stringValue = " ";
 var intValue = (int)stringValue[0];
```

A string is an 'array of chars' - so waht you need to do is get the char [in this case the first one] - and convert that to an int - in this case simply by casting.

If you want to do it with the enum, then you're going to have to write a manual system to convert " " to Keys.Space .

Answer (score 0):

If you review your *enum Keys* carefully, you will see there is no value for `[`.

In fact, that character (on my keyboard) is reported as Oem4.

This code works:

```
var c = kc.ConvertFromString("Oem4");
```

However,

```
var c = kc.ConvertFromString("[");
```

Cannot work because `[` is not a valid member of the enum you are converting from.

What do you want to do once you have converted the string?  That may help guide a better answer to your question.